# How to add smoke detail in Cycles X?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I use 3.0.1 for render smoke.

Settings

- Subdivision Domain 300
- 32 samples
- path trasing 0 all, 8 volume
- vorticity 0.2
- step rate volume 0.1

And have result [image]
But I need this (under blue arrow). [image]

How can I do this?
P.s. in old verstion was option @hi resolution smoke: but now I dont see it in new versions.

Comment: i think you should just increase the resolution division. Yes, that decreases the performance but just with high values there you will get amazing results.

Comment: no, its wrong way. Here author have best reseluts with 80 subdivision. https://youtu.be/4DfAJ7GD0t0 I have 250-300.

Comment: Of course you can believe in tube videos - I just can tell you from my own experience and yt making: they cut a lot, they make often things different than they are telling - it’s not that they do this always on purpose - sometimes they are just cutting wrong….

Comment: Yes, of course. But I cant increase the subdivide - its too hi. I 100% shure, that here is something with noise. But I dont understand, what.